# Block request via htaccess if host contains X

Tags: .htaccess

I have many bots that are accessing my site, and since they use mostly amazon web services to spam with the requests, in the logs it looks like that:

```
ec2-47-128-60-90.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
ad2-47-128-60-30.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

So i would like to know if it possible to create a rule that would block that request, if the host contains "compute.amazonaws.com"

I tried that but it didn't work:

```
Order Deny,Allow
SetEnvIf Remote_Host compute.amazonaws.com keep_out
Deny from env=keep_out
```

Also tried that but it didn't work:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from compute.amazonaws.com
```

Thanks for your help

PS: I'm using Apache 2.4

Answer (score 0):

OK so apparently it's because my server now uses Apache 2.4, which doesn't seem to support anymore the legacy 2.2 syntax.

Using this syntax might solve the problem on Apache 2.4.19+ :

```
<RequireAll> 
Require not forward-dns amazonaws.com 
</RequireAll>
```